# Merging attributes in pentaho (kettle)

Tags: attributes, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration

I have 2 tables, both have 2 primary keys (anys_mes_dia and aircraftreg) and each table has other attributes. I want to join both tables by the 2 PK.
The thing is, for some [any_mes_dia,aircraftreg] I have all the attributes of both tables but for others I only have the attribute of one table.
How can I join this tables so as to get [anys_mes_dia,aircraftreg,dy,add,cn] and only nulls in the attribute that a specitic row doesn't have.

Here an image of what I have (some rows only have aircraftreg_1, any_mes_dia1 and CN).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Merge join step you have the option to define the type of join, in this case you could use the LEFT/RIGHT OUTER join (depending on which table is leading) to get the results you want.